# sublime crashed with SublimeREPL command when output large data.

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I write python code with Sublime Text 3, and I install the SublimeREPL for its convenience to run PDB and console in sublime. But recently I found a problem,
when run the following code:

```
for i in xrange(100000):
    print i
```

1. when run the above code, with `Tools=>SublimeREPL=>Python=>Python-Run current file` , nothing is outputted and soon the Sublime is No response. And then after clicking on the editor, the sublime crashed.
2. I thought maybe the reason is the data is too much, but I tried using the Sublime build-in python command,`Tools=>build system=>Python`,it just output from 0 to 99999, nothing wrong happened
3. My os is WIN10, and Sublime version is Build 3114, python 2.7.3, and I have installed other package like, sublimerge, side bar, anaconda, sublimeClang, Terminal, ConverToUTF8, PythonPEP8AutoFormat.

it seems the problem of SublimeREPL, but I think it can be solved for build-in python command is ok, anyone can help me?